# Losing original stack trace in exception handling

Tags: c#, exception

I am trying to wrap my head around proper exception handling, so I've just been experimenting with this code:

```
 class MainClass
    {
        private static Logger logger = new Logger();

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            try
            {
                Method1("");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.Write(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private static void Method1(string text)
        {
            try
            {
                Method2(text);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.Write(ex);
                throw ex;
            }
            
        }

        private static void Method2(string text)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine(text[0]);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.Write(ex);
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

I notice in the exception logged in Method2, it shows that the error was thrown in the try block: `"Console.WriteLine(text[0])"`:

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
  at ExceptionHandlingTest.MainClass.Method2 (System.String text) [0x00002] in /ExceptionHandlingTest/Program.cs:40
```

But in the exception logged in Method1, it only shows it being thrown in the catch block: `throw;`:

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
  at ExceptionHandlingTest.MainClass.Method2 (System.String text) [0x00020] in /ExceptionHandlingTest/Program.cs:45 
  at ExceptionHandlingTest.MainClass.Method1 (System.String text) [0x00002] in //ExceptionHandlingTest/Program.cs:26
```

Am I doing something wrong here, or is it the way it is supposed to work?  The InnerException is null when I step into Method1.

I see that if I remove the try/catch from Method2, the exception in Method1 has the error in the Console.WriteLine as I was expecting.  I guess this leads me to wonder: how do I determine where/when to handle exceptions? It seems like as early as possible would be best.

Comment: Yes, read the [*important* box](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/throw).

Comment: That's what I am confused about, since in Method2 I am just using ```throw;``` and in Method1 immediately logging the exception before doing ```throw ex;```

Answer (score 0):

This pretty much works as expected. The explanation is as follows:

- `Method2` logs the exception with stack trace at `Console.WriteLine(text[0]);`:

  ```
  at [...].Method2(String text) in [...]:line 40
  ```
- `Method1` logs the exception with stack trace at `throw` which is in the `catch` block in `Method2`. Then, the next stack frame is at the `Method2(text);` call in `Method1` (stack trace is maintained because you used `throw`, not `throw ex`):

  ```
  at [...].Method2(String text) in [...]:line 45
  at [...].Method1(String text) in [...]:line 26
  ```
- In `Main`, you're not logging the exception; you're simply displaying the `.Message` property which *hides* what's going on from you. If you log the exception and check its track trace, you'll find that it starts at `throw ex`, then the next frame is at the call to `Method1("");`. In other words, there's a missing stack frame:

  ```
  at [...].Method1(String text) in [...]:line 31
  at [...].Main(String[] args) in [...]:line 10
  ```

  If you change `throw ex` to `throw` and log the exception caught in `Main`, the first stack frame is preserved:

  ```
  at [...].Method2(String text) in [...]:line 45
  at [...].Method1(String text) in [...]:line 31
  at [...].Main(String[] args) in [...]:line 10
  ```